# sed remove timezone from date string of ics file

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have very ics files that are malformed. Here is one example:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//cals.sig9.net//ptHolidays
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=Feriados Portugueses:MAILTO:nuno@sig9.net
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20221030T020000Z
DTEND:20221030T020100Z
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=pt_PT;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Portugal
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20211209T094211Z
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=pt_PT;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE: DST: Hora Inverno
PRIORITY:0
CLASS:PUBLIC
STATUS:CONFIRMED
UID:f59b372983f45e807fdac602160e3b96d5747708d86643e7ba1fc3aacd47087d
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

To be correct, I need to transform the dates in both `DTSTART` and `DTEND` from, for example, `20221030T020000Z` to `20221030`.

For that I am trying with this command:

```
sed -i s/T[[:digit:]]{6}Z//g *.ics
```

but the command is changing nothing, and I dont know why.

First, I need my command to work.
Then, I want it to apply only on `DTSTART` and `DTEND` (I want `DTSTAMP` time to stay intact) in order to make `calcurse` accept my ics files.

Comment: try adding `'` around your pattern string; your shell might be replacing `{6}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed  '/DTSTART\|DTEND/s/\(:[0-9]*\).*/\1/' input_file
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//cals.sig9.net//ptHolidays
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=Feriados Portugueses:MAILTO:nuno@sig9.net
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20221030
DTEND:20221030
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=pt_PT;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Portugal
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20211209T094211Z
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=pt_PT;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE: DST: Hora Inverno
PRIORITY:0
CLASS:PUBLIC
STATUS:CONFIRMED
UID:f59b372983f45e807fdac602160e3b96d5747708d86643e7ba1fc3aacd47087d
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```